# function push all data in first select of the v-for loop

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js

would like to call a function for all loop in my **v-for..** it's work but my function push data only on the first select...

```
<td style="min-width: 75px" v-for="date of dates" v-bind:key="date.id">
    <!-- Boucle for sur la date pour chaque utilisateur -->
    <form v-if="weekEnd(date)">
        <select v-bind:placeholder="generateTasksAM(user.id, date)" v-on:change="deleteTaskAM(user.id,date)" id="matin" size="1">

        </select>
    </form>
</td>
```

```
generateTasksAM: function(user, date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.assignments.length; i++) {
        var date1 = new Date(date);
        var date2 = new Date(this.assignments[i].start);

        if (user === this.assignments[i].User.id) {
            if (
              date1.getFullYear() === date2.getFullYear() &&
              date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() &&
              date1.getDate() === date2.getDate()
            ) {
            if (this.assignments[i].heuredebut <= "12:00:00") {
                for (var j = 0; j < this.options.length; j++) {
                    if (this.assignments[i].Task.Project.name === this.options[j]) {
                        var select = document.getElementById("matin");
                        select.options[j] = new Option(this.options[j],this.options[j],true,true);
                    } else {
                        var select = document.getElementById("matin");
                        select.options[j] = new Option(this.options[j],this.options[j],false,false);
```

Comment: you use `getElementById("matin")` in `generateTasksAM `method. so its return to you the first element from the v-for. this is why its only affect the first one. and btw touching the dom directly in vuejs is a bad practice. in other words you use the same id on serveal elements and the get only the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you to change to structure of your code without using a function to build your selects.

A way to achieve it could be using templates to replicate what you did in your function.

It's just an idea, not the working code.

Template:

```html
<select v-on:change="deleteTaskAM(user.id,date)" size="1">
  <template v-for="assignment in assignments">
    <template v-if="assignment.User.id == user.id">
      <template v-if="checkDates(date,assignment.start) && assignment.heuredebut <='12:00:00'">
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option" :selected="assignment.Task.Project.name === option">{{ option }}</option>
      </template>
    </template>
  </template>
</select>
```

Script:

```js
methods: {
  checkDates(date,start) {
    var date1 = new Date(date);
    var date2 = new Date(start);
    return date1.getFullYear() === date2.getFullYear() && date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() && date1.getDate() === date2.getDate()
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: it's nice ! but when the option is "" ( empty) the select is not create

Comment: Weird, it should. Every element of `options` array should be rendered if conditions matches, even if empty

Comment: ok so if  no condition matches i would like the same select but with a "" in selected

Comment: you can add another template tag with a `v-else` directive and within it a single option tag without `v-for`

Comment: i would like the empty value is call when the date don't have task but he doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you always get the same select when pushing options.

```
var select = document.getElementById("matin");
```

---

**SOLUTION**

Assign different ids to selectors.

`<select v-bind:placeholder="generateTasksAM(user.id, date)" v-on:change="deleteTaskAM(user.id,date)" :id="'matin-' + SOME_ID" size="1">`

`var select = document.getElementById('matin-' + SOME_ID);`

**Required modifications**

In template loop:

`<td style="min-width: 75px" v-for="(date, index) of dates" v-bind:key="index">`

In template select:

`<select v-bind:placeholder="generateTasksAM(user.id, date, index)" v-on:change="deleteTaskAM(user.id,date)" :id="'matin-' + index" size="1">`

In **generateTasksAM** function:

```
generateTasksAM: function(user, date, index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.assignments.length; i++) {
        var date1 = new Date(date);
        var date2 = new Date(this.assignments[i].start);

        if (user === this.assignments[i].User.id) {
            if (
              date1.getFullYear() === date2.getFullYear() &&
              date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() &&
              date1.getDate() === date2.getDate()
            ) {
            if (this.assignments[i].heuredebut <= "12:00:00") {
                for (var j = 0; j < this.options.length; j++) {
                    if (this.assignments[i].Task.Project.name === this.options[j]) {
                        var select = document.getElementById("matin-" + index);
                        select.options[j] = new Option(this.options[j],this.options[j],true,true);
                    } else {
                        var select = document.getElementById("matin-" + index);
                        select.options[j] = new Option(this.options[j],this.options[j],false,false);
```

Comment: ok bu't i can't increment SOME_ID in the two place in same time...

Comment: I updated my answer with required modifications for this solution.